# Finding max across Tensor of specific indices. (Bi-LSTM-max implementation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm am trying to implement BiLSTM-Max as described in the following paper: 
[Supervised Learning of Universal Sentence Representations from Natural Language Inference Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02364).

I am using Tensorflow for my implementation. I started off with an original LSTM code but have successfully made modifications so that it can run with dynamic length input and also bidirectional (i.e Dynamic Bi-LSTM).

```
# Bi-LSTM, returns output of shape [n_step, batch_size, n_input]
outputs = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x,dtype=tf.float32)
# Change output back to [batch_size, n_step, n_input]
outputs = tf.transpose(tf.stack(outputs), [1, 0, 2])
# Retrieve the last output corresponding the length of input sequence
batch_size_ = tf.shape(outputs)[0]
index = tf.range(0, batch_size_) * seq_max_len + (seqlen - 1)
outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, 2*n_hidden]), index)
```

Next modifying it to Bi-LSTM-Max, I replaced taking the last ouput and find the max across n_steps as follows:

```
# Bi-LSTM, returns output of shape [n_step, batch_size, n_input]
outputs = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x,dtype=tf.float32)
# Change output back to [batch_size, n_step, n_input]
outputs = tf.transpose(tf.stack(outputs), [1, 0, 2])
# Retrieve the max output across n_steps
outputs = tf.reduce_max(outputs, reduction_indices=[1])
```

When I took the max across the n_steps dimensions, I had assumed that those indices>seqlen are 0s, so I could take the max across the entire dimension instead of taking max from 0 to seqlen. Upon closer inspection, I realised that the values of the non assigned indices may be non-zero due to random initialization or it may just be the last assigned value in memory.

This operation is trivial in python arrays, however, for Tensor operation I can't find an easy way. Does anyone have an idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to manually set the invalid outputs to zero or -∞ before finding the maximum. You can do that quite easily with [`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) and [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```
seq_mask = tf.sequence_mask(seqlen, seq_max_len)
# You can also use e.g. -np.inf * tf.ones_like(outputs)
outputs_masked = tf.where(seq_mask, outputs, tf.zeros_like(outputs))
outputs = tf.reduce_max(outputs, axis=1)  # axis is preferred to reduction_indices
```

Comment: Great idea! It seems to be working now. But I had to add minor modifications to extend it from 2D to 3D. 
`seq_mask = tf.tile(seq_mask,[1,n_input])
 seq_mask = tf.reshape(seq_mask,[-1,n_input,seq_max_len])
seq_mask = tf.transpose(seq_mask, [0, 2, 1])`

Thanks so much!